# Ограничение одновременного выполнения асинхронной функции

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Нужно асинхронно выполнять функцию play().

Суть в том, что одновременно должна быть запущена всего одна функция play().

```
function quest() 
{
        return new Promise(resolve => {
        const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("GET", "https://ya.ru/index.php",true);
        http.send();
        http.timeout = 60000; 
                http.ontimeout = function () { }
        http.onload = () => resolve(http);
    });
}

async function play() 
{
    var myjson = await quest(); //получаем новый результат
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
        //делаем что-то
        setTimeout(function() 
        {
            //делаем что-то
            play();
        }, 20000);
    }, 20000);
}
setInterval( function() { play(); } , 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Заведите переменную-флаг, которая отвечает за статус «выполняется функция play». Если он `true` то заново `play` не выполняем, в конце функции `play` меняйте флаг на `false`, в начале функции на `true`